# Firebase Plugin issue in Phonegap Build app

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I need to send notification to my app using firebase or phonegap push plugin. I have added facebook & google plus login plugins and building it using Phonegap Build. When my app opens it first checks the facebook login & then the google login and then proceeds accordingly.

On using **push plugin**, google login works but when I send the notification from my Firebase console then the app stops & closes.

So I switched to **firebase plugin :**

Firstly there were many conflicts but somehow I have crossed those conflicts as the two plugins (Google Plus & Firebase) were conflicting and the build was failing. After many hit & trials & googling out, as of now the app builds successfully but when I open the first screen, i.e. index.html, the facebook login is checked, it crosses it, **then google login is checked**, **& this is where it hangs,**  I still try to send notification from Firebase console while the app is in hang status but it says **ERROR SENDING MESSAGE**. But on disabling the firebase plugin the google login plugin works seamlessly. So I ended up nowhere now.

Neither able to use Push Plugin nor Firebase plugin. Is there any way out by which I can send notifications?

Below I have mentioned my config.xml.  In my index.html I have just the google plus plugin check that's it & I have not included any file for firebase. I have also placed the google-services.json file in my app folder.

**config.xml :**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

        <widget id="com.phonegap.myapp1" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
            <name>MyApp</name>
            <description>
              My App
            </description>
            <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
                sqlchild
            </author><allow-navigation href="*" />


                <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" /> 

                <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-8.0.0' />

                <preference name='pgb-builder-version' value='2' />



            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="5.0.2"/>  


            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />  




                <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" source="npm" spec="2.0.0">
                    <string name="fb_app_id">xxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
                    <string name="fb_app_name">my first app</string>

                    <param name="APP_ID" value="xxxxxxxxx" />
                    <param name="APP_NAME" value="my first app" />
                </plugin>


                <platform name="android">
                    <config-file parent="/resources" target="./res/values/strings.xml">
                        <string name="fb_app_id">xxxxxxxxx</string>
                        <string name="fb_app_name">my first app</string>
                    </config-file>
                </platform>     


                <hook src="scripts/cordova-google-services-version-gradle-fix.js" type="before_prepare" />


                <platform name="android">

                    <!-- <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+" /> -->
                    <!-- <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0" /> -->
                    <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0" />

                    <!-- <framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:+" /> -->
                    <!-- <framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:11.8.0" /> -->
                    <framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:9.0.0" />

                </platform>


            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" source="npm" spec="5.3.0"></plugin>  

            <platform name="android">   

                <resource-file src="app/google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />  

            </platform>      


            <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="0.1.20" /> 

            <content src="index.html" />

</widget>
```